# Elastic Search reindex API - how to preserve destination index mapping?

Tags: elasticsearch, reindex

Let **my-index-0** be an ES index with an alias of **my-index**.

It has the following mapping:

```json
{
    "my-index-0": {
        "aliases": {
            "my-index": {}
        },
        "mappings": {
            "doc": {
                "properties": {
                    "foo": {
                        "properties": {
                            "fizz": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            },
                            "baz": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say I want to remove the `baz` field from `foo`. I'm using the following steps:

1. Create a new index `my-index-1` with updated mapping (`foo.baz` removed) using `PUT /my-index-1`

```json
{
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "properties": {
                "foo": {
                    "properties": {
                        "fizz": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. Reindex data from `my-index-0` to `my-index-1` using `POST /_reindex`

```json
{
  "source": {
    "index": "my-index-0"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "my-index-1"
  }
}
```

3. Move the `my-index` alias to the `my-index-1` index using `POST /_aliases`

```json
{
    "actions": [
        {"remove": {"index": "my-index-0", "alias": "my-index"}},
        {"add": {"index": "my-index-1", "alias": "my-index"}},
    ]
}
```

### Expected result

Data in the new index does not have the `foo.baz` property.

### Actual result

On `my-index-1` creation, its mapping does not contain the `foo.baz` field, however, after re-indexation, `my-index-1`'s mapping is changed to the old index' mapping.

### Note: `_source` can be used for simple fields removal

If one wants to remove a field, for example, removal of `bar` from the mapping below

```json
{
    "mappings": {
        "foo": {
            "type": "text"
        },
        "bar": {
            "type": "text"
        }
    }
}
```

it is sufficient to provide the `_source` param without the `bar` field in the request to reindex API:

```json
{
  "source": {
    "index": "my-index-0",
    "_source": ["foo"]
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "my-index-1"
  }
}
```

How to achieve the same with a nested structure?

Answer (score 10):

When you use `reindex` ES tries to copy all data from source to destination index. If you want to make your index to not to be modified you need to add this line to your mapping:

```json
"dynamic" : "strict"
```

Now if you want to `reindex` data you will get an error `"strict_dynamic_mapping_exception"` because `"mapping set to strict, dynamic introduction of [baz] within [foo] is not allowed"`. So you need to delete this field in your `reindex` like this:

```json
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "my-index-0"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "my-index-1"
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.remove(\"foo.baz\")"
  }
}
```

Note: adding `"dynamic" : "strict"` is optional and prevents your index from modifying. It will work for you if you just edit your `reindex` query.

Comment: This is an excellent remark! I thought of using the "script", but in a general case ([see my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69663156/8091093)) it seemed to be harder to handle.

The problem is, that I want to be able to handle arbitrally indices, without the necessity to write custom `reindex` queries for each case.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the generic solution I was looking for.

In the `_source` attribute, one can specify explicitly every nested field, therefore, the `_source` value for the scenario in the example should be `["foo.fiz"]` - note the lack of `"foo.bar"` which **shouldn't** be copied.

```json
{
  "source": {
    "index": "my-index-0",
    "_source": ["foo.fiz"]
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "my-index-1"
  }
}
```

Essentially, the problem of generating the `"_source"` attribute for a generic case, can be reduced to finding the intersection of sets of all property paths for old and new mappings.

#### Python solution

The function below Recursively iterate through properties and yield all property paths.

```py
def get_property_path(properties: dict[str, Any], name: str = "") -> Iterator[str]:
    for property_name, property_value in properties.items():
        new_name = f"{name}.{property_name}" if name else property_name
        if nested_properties := property_value.get("properties"):
            yield from get_property_path(nested_properties, new_name)
        else:
            yield new_name
```

for example

```py
>>> properties = {
    "a": {
        "properties": {
            "b": {
                "properties": {
                    "c": {"type": "text"},
                },
            },`
        },
    },
    "e": {
        "properties": {
            "f": {"type": "text"},
        },
    },
}
>>> list(get_property_path(properties))
>>> ['a.b.c', 'e.f']
```

It can be later used to calculate the set of fields that should be copied (fields that are both in old and new mapping):

```py
_source = list(
    set(get_property_path(old_mapping["properties"]))
    & set(get_property_path(new_mapping["properties"]))
)
```

I won't accept my answer tho, as there might be a simpler solution that is based on the ES API.